# CSS file not linking even though it's in the same file

Tags: html, css, express

Both of these file have the correct names and are located in the exact same file. However, for some reason the CSS isn't styling the page at all. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css"/>
    <title>Transitions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="show">BORING</p>
    <p class="animated box">ANIMATED</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the file structure:

[image]

Comment: Remove the `/` in `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css"/>`

Comment: Don't think the ending `/` matters

Comment: @j08691 There's nothing wrong with having the slash.

Comment: check the spelling of the file app.css, also in your question you say they are in the same file are they in seperate files like the image in my answer?

Comment: Where is your html file above? in your image it is a ejs in the same folder as the css. Is the above the ejs file?

Comment: @jhpratt If you had taken the time to try and validate that code then you'd see there is. Especially without a doctype.

Comment: @j08691 Please explain the difference, then, because the trailing slash is optional in HTML5. A DOCTYPE is not required. I'm incredibly familiar with the syntax.

Comment: @jhpratt Just drop it in [here](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and see. Why do I have to do the work for you?

Comment: Hey, I just tried removing the slash and nothing has changed. I've also tried adding !<Doctype HTML> which has also had no effect. Thank you all so much for the help.

Comment: @j08691 You realize no one _ever_ validates their code, right? The validator is always out of date, anyways, as acknowledged by the W3C. No need to be rude, I'm on mobile so I can't.

Comment: @jhpratt, @j08691 - validator gives a warning with `<link />`, but when the doctype is specified, it gives no errors or warnings with or without trailing slash

Comment: Have you tried putting the app.css in the root of your site - it looks as if the home file is just a template that is being served by another file so the css doesn't actually want to be relative to that file, but the file that serves it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up your `views` folder a static directory first.

```
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"));
```

Then reference like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/app.css' />
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: the 'ejs' file is an HTML equivalent.

Comment: I just tried implementing the link you wrote but nothing changed. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Edited my answer with a new solution, give this a shot to see if it works for you

Comment: That worked! thank you so much! I was completely stumped. This should have been a really basic thing to do but it just wansn't working. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad it helped you out! :-)